# How can I make a button group when one is selected the others are unselected Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have bunch of buttons on the screen and I set them such that when clicked the background color changes to red.
multiple buttons can be clicked this way and become red.
**I want that you would be able to select only one at a time**
I mean when a button is clicked then it will be the only one in red and the others will be with their natural color. kind of like a radio buttons.

Here is my code:
**HTML:**

```js
//creating buttons for picking coins
function createButton(type, className, id, value, onclickFunction) {
  //comments are for the coins buttons:
  var button = document.createElement("input"); // input type is the simplest
  button.type = type; //"button";
  button.className = className; // 'Button';
  button.id = id; // id;
  button.value = value; // id;
  button.onclick = onclickFunction; // ""

  //adding the just created coin to screen
  var divCoinPickScrn = document.getElementById("arrayStatus");
  divCoinPickScrn.appendChild(button);
  var space = document.createTextNode(" ");
  divCoinPickScrn.appendChild(space);


}

$(document).ready(function() {

  //creating 99 buttons with id same as their number:
  for (var i = 2; i <= 100; i++) { // function createButton(type , className , id , value , onclickFunction)
    createButton('button', 'button', i, i, "");
  }

  // listener for clicking
  $('.Button').click(function(e) {

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.Button:active,
.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- for displaying the array with every number as a BUTTON-->
<div id="arrayStatus">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working only problem is `.Button` which is in caps.It should be `.button`.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/1uuLt90e/)

Code:

```js
//creating buttons for picking coins
function createButton(type, className, id, value, onclickFunction) {
  //comments are for the coins buttons:
  var button = document.createElement("input"); // input type is the simplest
  button.type = type; //"button";
  button.className = className; // 'Button';
  button.id = id; // id;
  button.value = value; // id;
  button.onclick = onclickFunction; // ""

  //adding the just created coin to screen
  var divCoinPickScrn = document.getElementById("arrayStatus");
  divCoinPickScrn.appendChild(button);
  var space = document.createTextNode(" ");
  divCoinPickScrn.appendChild(space);


}

$(document).ready(function() {

  //creating 99 buttons with id same as their number:
  for (var i = 2; i <= 100; i++) { // function createButton(type , className , id , value , onclickFunction)
    createButton('button', 'button', i, i, "");
  }

  // listener for clicking
  $('.button').click(function(e) {
    $('.button').removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.button:active,
.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="arrayStatus">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First there is a type issue in your createButton call, you dont set the proper class

```
createButton('button' , 'Button' , i , i , "");
```

(upper B for second parameter)

Then simply remove the active class from all button before adding it to the clicked one should do the trick

```
 $('.Button').click(function(e) {
    $('.Button').removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

working sample : https://jsfiddle.net/6yhg8qv7/